# Как при помощи SIMPLE HTML DOM парсера вывести последовательно все блоки с одинаковыми классами?

Tags: php, парсер

Парсер выводит только последний элемент с классом motion а их на странице несколько. Как вывести все?

Comment: покажите, что делаете. попробуем подсказать

Comment: $html = file_get_html('http://site.ru');

    foreach ($html->find(".motion") as $elsements) {
      $categories = $elsements;
    }
    echo $categories;   выводит только последний блок с этим классом

Comment: foreach ($html->find(".motion") as $elements) {
   $categories[] = $elements;
  }

Comment: на вид, всё правильно. а длина массива тоже 1?

Comment: убедитесь, что остальные блоки не аяксом добавляются. Ткните правой кнопкой в страницу в браузере и посмотрите исходный html код, сколько там этих блоков